# syslogs getting spammed with 'context mismatch in svga_sampler_view_destroy'

Tags: debian, logs, vmware-workstation

I'm running a Debian (Gnome) distro on a VMWARE Workstation 12.

The linux syslogs are getting spammed with:

> gnome-settings-daemon.desktop[1411]: context mismatch in
>   svga_sampler_view_destroy

Anyone come across a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "Accelerate 3D Graphic" option of the VM setting. 
The VM should be powered off in order to disable this option.